# Arange ordinal number for range of values in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have some kind of data frame which, and in one column values range from 139 to 150 (rows with values repeat). How to create new column, which will assign ordinal value based on the mentioned column? For example, 139 -> 0, 140 -> 1, ..., 150 -> 10

UPD: Mozway's answer is suitable, thanks!

Comment: Post some code demonstrating where you've run into a problem?

Comment: use dict? ``'139': '0'`` and so on

Comment: `df.groupby('x').ngroup()` or `df.x.astype('category').cat.codes`

Comment: Given these are numbers in a contiguous block subtraction as [@mozway suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69230058/15497888) seems most reasonable. Assuming you're trying to convert _any_ categorical to ordinal values the standard approach is [factorize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) `df['new col'] = pd.factorize(df['col'])[0]`

Comment: Anyway, I will open new question with more clear explanation

Comment: That doesn't make sense. factorize does in sorted order. `pd.factorize(range(139, 151))[0]` gives `[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]` A sample of your dataframe is _super_ helpful. `df.to_dict()` or something similar to reproduce.

Comment: @HenryEcker yeah, my bad, not that good explanation. I meant that values repeat. They are not in order, but like [ 139 139 140 139 149 145 150 ] within the range (139, 151). Every value has its own order within this range, so the desirbale output is [ 1 1 2 1 10 6 11]

Comment: Ah. And why doesn't @mozway's answer work?

Comment: I read it more clearly and I guess I'm just dumb, overcomplicating simple stuff after a hard day.... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Simply subtract 139:  `df['col'] -= 139`

Or, to get a new column: `df['new'] = df['col'] - 139`

Comment: @Michael I guess this is an error in the question. If not, OP should explain the logic.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, trying to figure out how to input data in the decent way